# Revising a previously published Dart package version

Tags: flutter, dart

I have published many versions of a Dart package, but I want to go back an update a previous version. Let's say I have published these versions:

```
1.0.0 - first version
1.1.0 - minor update
2.0.0 - major update with breaking changes
```

I would like to go back and publish version 1.2.0 with a small change to 1.1.0 code, but not use the 2.0.0 code. If I use pub publish with version 1.2.0, will it add it to the versioning list correctly, or will it use publish date order instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that it should work correctly, and if it doesn't, it would be a bug that should be reported.

As an example, [the versions of the `path_provider` package](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider/versions) show that version 1.6.28 was uploaded after 2.0.0 and 2.0.1, but 2.0.1 (as of writing) is advertised as the latest stable version.

Comment: I think it worked. https://pub.dev/packages/upgrader/versions/2.8.3